# Python ModuleNotFoundError by importing gspread

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-module, gspread

I successfully installed the module gspread via

```
pip install gspread
```

When I import the module in my Python scrip

```
import gspread
```

I got the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread'
```

I tried to import other module in the script, e.g.

```
import numpy
```

... and this working properly.

I tried via the terminal, launching Python and importing the same module, I got exactly the same behavior.

I'm using Python v3.7.3.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by installing the module via pip3

```
pip3 install gspread
```

Now it works properly.